# Affixed top navbar covers anchor's content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

It's a landing page with fixed navbar and anchors in a content using bootstrap scrollspy and affix. I have added affix on my top navbar via data attributes. Everything is working well, except that affixed top navbar covers top of the content.

**This is how it is at this moment:**

[image]

**And this is how it should be:**

[image]

navbar code:

```
<!-- navbar section -->

<nav id="navbar-scrollspy" class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="58" data-offset-bottom="200">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#first_round"><strong>ГЛАВНАЯ</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#second_round">КАК ЭТО <strong>РАБОТАЕТ</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="#third_round">КАК ПОЛУЧИТЬ <strong>ЗАЙМ</a></strong></li>
                <li><a href="#fourth_round">КАК ВЕРНУТЬ <strong>ЗАЙМ</a></strong></li>
                <li><a href="#fifth_round">ОТЗЫВЫ <strong>О НАС</a></strong></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's live example: http://zaim.wvb.io/

Answer (score 0):

Remember as you scroll, the navbar-scrollspy element changes its classes.. With scroll at the top of the screen the classes available are `class="navbar navbar-default affix-top"`  After you scroll down a bit, the classes change to `class="navbar navbar-default affix"`  Because that top element flips from `position: relative` to `position: fixed`, the bottom margin gets wonky.

I'd rather see you add a margin top (45px?) to `class="container form-itself"` and reduce the margin-bottom from the class `navbar` (from 45px to 0).   That would protect you everywhere.

Oops. and speaking of wonky.  That same menu needs some work in mobile, but I'm guessing you haven't gotten there yet. I share your pain.

Comment: I have updated the link. I have this css rule already:

```
#navbar-scrollspy.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```